# Micronaut: Exception Handler is not invoked while executing Mockito tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito, micronaut

When I create a case where exception is thrown by the code by calling APIs, at that time, `ExceptionHandler` is invoked as expected. But when I try creating the same case through unit tests, at that time, `ExceptionHandler` is not invoked. My classes are as below:

**Controller.java**

```
@Post("/XXX")
public ResponseEntity<List<CategoryTopicBean>> listCategoryTopics(@Body CategoryIdsRequestBean categoryIdsRequestBean) {
    if (categoryIdsRequestBean.getCategoryIds().size() > MAX_ALLOWED_CATEGORY_SELECTION) {
        throw new CustomException(SystemConstants.ResponseCode.ERROR, SystemConstants.ResponseMessage.OVERFLOW_MAX_CATEGORIES);
    }
    ...
```

**CustomExceptionHandler.java:**

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {CustomException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class CustomExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<CustomException, HttpResponse> {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, CustomException exception) {
        return HttpResponse.ok(new ResponseEntity<>(exception.responseCode, exception.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

**XXXShould.java**

```
@Test
public void should_list_category_topics() {
    CategoryIdsRequestBean categoryIdsBean = new CategoryIdsRequestBean();
    IdBean idBean = new IdBean();
    idBean.setId(ID_1);
    categoryIdsBean.setCategoryIds(Arrays.asList(idBean));

    ResponseEntity<List<CategoryTopicBean>> responseEntity = topicController.listCategoryTopics(categoryIdsBean);
    assertThat(SystemConstants.ResponseCode.SUCCESS).isEqualTo(responseEntity.getResponseCode());
    assertThat(1).isEqualTo(responseEntity.getData().size());

    categoryIdsBean = new CategoryIdsRequestBean();
    categoryIdsBean.setCategoryIds(Arrays.asList(idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean));
    responseEntity = topicController.listCategoryTopics(categoryIdsBean);
}
```

Can anyone please look into this, and help me out?

Comment: Did you get a way of testing the exception handlers during unit testing ?

Comment: Please, can you include in your question how you are initializing your topiccontroller in your test?

Comment: I personally have tried injecting the controller with @Inject but if I do that, the exception handlers are not invoked.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are instantiating it directly, aren't you? If it is the case, the @GoviS answer will be the right one: if you instantiate the controller directly, it is only a normal java class, without any added functionally provided by the framework. This is precisely the reason why I asked you how the topicontroller was initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, you are testing the controller  by directly invoking the controller method
`topicController.listCategoryTopics(categoryIdsBean)`.

This is not a good approach to test controller functionality. What you should do is use [MicronautTest](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/). MicronautTest will start an embedded server. Now you can use an HTTP client to hit the endpoint and retrieve the result.

Your code needs to be changed to something around the lines as below.

```
@MicronautTest
class HelloWorldTest {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxHttpClient client;

    @Test
    public void should_list_category_topics() {
        // Test Data
        CategoryIdsRequestBean categoryIdsBean = new CategoryIdsRequestBean();
        IdBean idBean = new IdBean();
        idBean.setId(ID_1);
        categoryIdsBean.setCategoryIds(Arrays.asList(idBean));

        HttpRequest<String> request = HttpRequest.POST("/XXX", categoryIdsBean);
        ResponseEntity<List<CategoryTopicBean>> retrieve = client.toBlocking().retrieve(request, ResponseEntity.class);

        categoryIdsBean = new CategoryIdsRequestBean();
        categoryIdsBean.setCategoryIds(Arrays.asList(idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean, idBean));
        responseEntity = topicController.listCategoryTopics(categoryIdsBean);
    }
}
```

For the `exception` case scenario, as the exception handler returns `ResponseEntity<String>`, you would need to make a minor change in the above code.

```
ResponseEntity<String> retrieve = client.toBlocking()
                               .retrieve(request, ResponseEntity.class);
```

If your controller calls any other service, do not forget to mock the behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But what I have shown code is of unit test of controller, not integration test or functional test. So I need to write the code as shown. Is there a better way to do unit test?

Comment: @KrutiParekh In a Unit test, you should treat a method under test as an independent unit i.e you shouldn't check the exception handler logic in a unit test. In my view, you can test whether `listCategoryTopics` throws an exception when `size()  > MAX_ALLOWED_CATEGORY_SELECTION`. Integration test cases fits a lot better for your case.